# Replace text after underscore from rows of a column of a dataframe in dplyr pipe

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, stringr

An example df:

```
 a = c("a_1", "b_1", "b_2", "b_3", "c_1")
 b = c(1,2,3,4,5)
 df = cbind.data.frame(a,b)
```

How do I replace all text after, and including, _ using str_replace in dplyr pipe?

The following does not work:

```
df_1 = df %>% filter(b >= 1.5) %>% str_replace_all(df$a, "_*", "")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the `.`, use `_.*` instead. Since `_*` matches zero or more underscores, notice `*` is a quantifier that specifies the quantity of direct afore character; while `_.*` matches an underscore and then everything after `.*` since `.` matches a general character;

```
df %>% mutate(new_a = str_replace(a, '_.*', as.character(b)))

#    a b new_a
#1 a_1 1    a1
#2 b_1 2    b2
#3 b_2 3    b3
#4 b_3 4    b4
#5 c_1 5    c5
```

Or if you just wanted to remove the trailing part:

```
df %>% mutate(new_a = str_replace(a, '_.*', ''))

#    a b new_a
#1 a_1 1     a
#2 b_1 2     b
#3 b_2 3     b
#4 b_3 4     b
#5 c_1 5     c
```

Comment: Thanks. I want to remove the underscore as well. I changed my question accordingly.

Comment: Yes. You need to use mutate if you want to add a new column to or modify a column of the data frame